How to compute the homology group of $n$-simplex directly?
Define the standard $n$-simplex to be
$$
\Delta^n := \left\{ (x_0, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} : \sum_{k = 0}^{n} x_k = 1, \ x_k \ge 0 \right\}.
$$
By the fact that homology groups are homotopy invariant, it is easy to check that
$$
H_k (\Delta^n)
=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \mathbb{Z}, & k = 0, \\
 0, & k \ne 0.
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
I wonder if we can calculate it directly by definition.

Maybe I should clarify how I define the chain homology of $\Delta^n$ at first, since there are lots of approaches, which are essentially the same. My way is as follows. First we define
$$
e_i := (0, \dots, 0, \underbrace{1}_{i\text{-th}}, 0, \dots, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^{n + 1}, \qquad (i = 0, 1, \dots, n).
$$
For each order-preverving injection $\lambda : \{ 0, 1, \dots, k \} \to \{ 0, 1, \dots, n \}$, we may obatin a unique $\mathbb{R}$-linear map
\begin{align*}
 \lambda_* : \mathbb{R}^{k + 1} & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n + 1} \\
 e_k & \longmapsto e_{\lambda(k)}.
\end{align*}
We say the maps with the form of
$$
\sigma_\lambda := \lambda_* |_{\Delta^k} : \Delta^k \to \Delta^n
$$
to be $k$-dimensional facets of $\Delta^n$. In particular, the $(n - 1)$-dimensional facets are called the faces, denoted by $\partial_i$'s $(i = 0, 1, \dots, n)$. Define
$$
C_k^\Delta (\Delta^n) := \bigoplus_{ n\text{-dim facets} } \mathbb{Z},
$$
and
\begin{align*}
 d_k : C_k^\Delta (\Delta^n) & \longrightarrow C_{k - 1}^\Delta (\Delta^n) \\
 \sigma_{\lambda} & \longmapsto \sum_{i = 0}^{n} (-1)^i \sigma_\lambda \circ \partial_{i}.
\end{align*}
Then we obtain a chain complex about $\Delta^n$:
$$
\cdots \xrightarrow{d} C_{k + 1}^\Delta (\Delta^n) \xrightarrow{d} C_k^\Delta (\Delta^n) \xrightarrow{d} C_{k - 1}^\Delta (\Delta^n) \xrightarrow{d} \cdots
$$

I can check that it is indeed a chain complex. And I can prove that
$$
H_k (\Delta^0)
=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \mathbb{Z}, & k = 0, \\
 0, & k \ne 0.
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
But for the general $\Delta^n$, it is really hard for me to calculate $\ker (d_k)$ and $\operatorname{im}(d_{k - 1})$ by definition. I looked up this question, whose answer did this by homotopy invariant property. I wonder if it can be done directly by definition.

I do not think that there is an elementary way to show that $H_k(\Delta^n) = 0$ for $k \ne 0$. The chain complex $C_*(\Delta^n)$ is so big for $n > 0$ that you need sophisticated arguments to reduce it up to chain homotopy equivalence  to something manageable.

One approach is to notice that an $N$-simplex is the cone of an $(N-1)$-simplex.
The cone $CX$ of a simplicial complex $X$ has as its $i$-cells
$$
    (CX)^i := X^i \sqcup \{[v_0, \dots, v_{i-1}, N]:[v_0,\dots, v_{i-1}] \in X^{i-1}\},
$$ for some new vertex we can call $N$.
Here's the lemma: the cone $CX$ of any simplicial complex $X$ has the simplicial homology of a point ($\mathbb{Z}$ only in dimension zero, trivial otherwise).
One way of proving this is by what is called a chain homotopy, which is an entirely algebraic trick analogous to the topological idea of homotopy. We define a map $h_i \colon C_i(CX) \to C_{i+1}(CX)$ by
\begin{align*}
    &h_i([v_0, \dots, v_{i-1}, N]) := 0\\
    &h_i([v_0, \dots, v_i]) := (-1)^{i+1}h_i([v_0, \dots, v_i, N]), \text{ if $v_i\neq N$}
\end{align*}
Expanding out the definitions and combining the like terms, we can actually prove that
$$
    d_{n+1} \circ h_{n} + h_{n-1}\circ d_n = \operatorname{id}_{C_n(CX)}.
$$
(check two cases: those simplices ending in $N$ and those not).
Now using this fact, if $\sigma \in \ker d_n$, then
\begin{align*}
    \sigma
    &= \operatorname{id}_{C_n(CX)}(\sigma)
    \\&= d_{n+1}(h_n(\sigma)) + h_{n-1}(d_n(\sigma))
    \\&= d_{n+1}(h_n(\sigma)) + h_{n-1}(0)
    \\&= d_{n+1}(h_n(\sigma))
    \\&\in \operatorname{im}(d_{n+1}).
\end{align*}
So $\ker d_n = \operatorname{im}(d_{n+1})$, so we get trivial homology.
I'll leave it to you to make the appropriate adjustments in dimension $0$ to see the $\mathbb{Z}$. (or else use reduced homology with an "empty simplex" $[]$ in dimension $-1$)
Basically the chain homotopy worked as a machine that in this case tells us, for any given cycle $\sigma$, which $(n+1)$-chain $h_n(\sigma)$ satisfies $d_{n+1}(h_n(\sigma)) = \sigma$.

But this is what OP wants to avoid: they just want to use the definition.

In that case all one has to do is to rewrite the proof inserting the formula for values of $h_n$ wherever they occur, and then erase the statement of the lemma and the definition of chain homotopy... which may seem kind of silly but is often an appropriate answer for "I can't use X, Y, or Z" problems.

Indeed, this becomes a concrete recipe for writing cycles as boundaries. For example, it gives that the 1-cycle $[0,2] - [0, 3] + [2, 3]$ within the 5-simplex $\Delta^5=[0,1,2,3,4,5]$ is the boundary of $[0,2,5] - [0,3,5] + [2,3,5]$. It similarly gives that the 2-cycle $[3,4,5] - [0,4,5] + [0,3,5] - [0,3,4]$ is the boundary of $[0,3,4,5]$. I'm not invoking any facts about topology or chain homotopy when defining $h_n$--I only mention the term for the sake of recording where the idea came from.
